# Can't get php5-ldap module to be enabled

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.6, phpldapadmin

I have installed php5-ldap module in ubuntu and running

```
   dpkg -l|grep ldap shows  
        ldap-utils                        2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.6         OpenLDAP utilities
    ii  libaprutil1-ldap                  2+deb.sury.org~precise+1        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - LDAP Driver
     ii  libldap-2.4-2                     2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.6                   OpenLDAP libraries
    ii  php5-ldap                         5.5.30+dfsg-             1+deb.sry.org~precise+1  LDAP module for php5



   But when i am running php_info() it doesn't show ldap is enabled.
```

I commented extension=php_ldap.dll in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
but it is still not working

I read somewhere i also need to add extension=ldap.so.But i am not sure where to add it.Can someone please help?

Comment: on *nix systems you should use `extension=php_ldap.so` instead of `extension=php_ldap.dll` also check if your [extension_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) is set properly. dlls are for windows system

Comment: I thought so but i don't know why all the files are under .dll extension instead of *.so in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. and also how to check extension_dir is set properly?

Comment: the ` extension_dir` is normally properly set if you have installed php in normal folder. it is in the same php.ini file. check if the path points to `ext` folder in the php folder. don't know about the dll extension may be a wrong ini file got into the package.